# How to get a more refined and smooth DEM?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, dem, 3d-map

I have Two DEMs (Digital Elevation models)

1. DEM (Image 1) - received from my institute
2. DEM (Image 2) - downloaded from srtm

Both DEMs have been styled similarly. But DEM (Image 1) looks better than DEM (Image 2). The resolution of both the DEMs is also same that is 30m X 30m.[image][image]

My question is why they look differently after doing same styling in qgis and how I can get such DEMs as in image 1.

My OneDrive link to download the images is
https://1drv.ms/u/s!At3AD05XRRsNiFQRmp2KCiO1Mkmf?e=i6Owf9

Comment: your catchment.tif is only 96 dpi - you need 300dpi+ to improve the image quality.

Comment: Thanks for reply. What is dpi?? where can I get 300 dpi? DEMs?

Comment: Would you please help to say how I can get the dpi of a DEM.

Comment: dpi = dots per inch (the more dots inside an inch the high resolution). To get the dpi right click on the file and view properties (in windows).

Comment: DEM's not sure where your sources came from? - but if a web site - the images may have been reduced to speed up web rendering.